# Do any humans wear glasses?

Tags: star-wars

Do we ever see a human in Star Wars wearing glasses or other visible, non-mask vision-correcting devices?  I know that Vader and the StormTroopers see augmented vision displays inside their helmets, but that's not what I mean.

Comment: Thousands of years of light sabers, someone is going to stumble on laser eye surgery :-)

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Spectacles

Comment: Since you can't get any more answers now that this has been closed, would you like to accept mine? Or should I add more to it to make it better first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes.

See [this page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Spectacles) from Star Wars Wikia.

E.g. [Noa Briqualon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Noa_Briqualon) from [Ewoks: the Battle for Endor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ewoks:_The_Battle_for_Endor):

[image: NB]

Also (thanks to @Richard) [Saun Dann](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Saun_Dann) from the Holiday Special:

[image: SD]